# make OSX commanline argument place independent

Tags: macos, command-line

When I run this command under linux, it works:

```
rm xxx -rf
```

but in OSX, I must place arguments ahead, like is:

```
rm -rf xxx
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I don't think so, unless you're willing to do some programming on behalf of BSD folks. OS/X ie. Darwin comes with mostly BSD userland and these things parse command line arguments in a very different style than GNU userland utilities used in most GNU/Linux distributions. GNU fileutils which include `rm` could be compiled to Darwin, though. There might even be a Homebrew (http://brew.sh) formula for that.

Comment: That means parsing method is build into binary executable? then there is no way to work it out, or write another commandline tool or shell script to "reorder" the arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/rm.html) actually requires placing option arguments before non-option arguments:

> #### SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> rm [-fiRr] file...
> ```

GNU/Linux doesn't conform to POSIX but OS X does. If you set POSIXLY_CORRECT, GNU rm doesn't allow placing non-option arguments before option arguments either:

```
$ touch a;grm a -rf
$ touch a;POSIXLY_CORRECT= grm a -rf
grm: cannot remove ‘-rf’: No such file or directory
```

If you want to replace OS X's rm with GNU rm, run `brew install coreutils` and add `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin` before other directories on the path.